# Bluetooth in java (J2SE)

Tags: java, bluetooth, 32bit-64bit, bluecove

I am a newbie  to bluetooth and this is the thing i want to do ,
I want to to get the device information that gets connected to the Bluetooth on my pc and write the info in a file. which api should i use and how to implement . I came across bluecove but on a few searches i found that bluecove doesn't work on 64 bit pc's. what should i do now .i want this to work on both 32 bit and 64 bit pcs.

Thankx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bluetooth apis recommended in the oracle tutorials are included in the `JSR 82` API specification.

I think though, that the latest release of the BlueCove (2.1.1)includes the driver for windows 7 64.

check:

http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/

You can download the JSR 82 specification and source code here:

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr082/index2.html

A good oracle tutorial how to start is:

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/

And here is also a good practical example:

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html

Comment: the JSR-82 standard is supported by various libraries. I am not sure but I think Atinav works fine on 64 bit.

Comment: The last stable (and I think final forever is 2.1). We use it for 64 bit arch. the project is now here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/downloads